# CRuntime mixing non-issue doesnt seem explainable and how to sensibly upgrade codebase

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, dll, crt

Apologies for my lack of understanding on this subject. I am a little uncertain about what I have read, and especially how it relates to our real-world source/scenario and how to move forwards with it.

A job ahead of me is to upgrade a large and ancient VC++ code base (currently building and running ok as a Visual Studio 2010 project) to use VS2013 IDE/compiler tools. Until now, this has been built with VS2010 tools & IDE successfully for ~6 years now and is considered stable. Win 7 / 8 / 10 being the target.

I started looking at potential issues with a VS2013 IDE/compiler/linker upgrade and came across the issue of mixing CRT libraries (lots of warnings against, lots of issues reported, not much knowledge on CRT issues for my part). I didn’t expect to find a problem as our code is currently stable - but the following (?nightmare?) became apparent fairly quickly.

I started here, which was a good starting eye-opener:
http://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/

and eventually found that I had the following mix:

```
Application.exe     statically links LIBCMT.lib using VS2010 toolchain (- but isnt LIBCMT very old, like VC6?)
lib A           statically links LIBCMT.lib. This is our library. Same as above.
lib B           statically links LIBCMT.lib. This is our library. Same as above.
lib C           statically links with "-MT". Not our library (& no clue as to which version of LIBCMT. Could be anything)
dll 1           dynamically links MSVCRT.dll. Not our dll. (again, isnt this VC6, or very old? Reading suggests could be v4.2 - v6)
dll 2           as dll1
Windows dlls...     Many of these. Eg, wininet, depends on MSVCRT.dll (MSVCR1xx version expected, but old MSVCRT referenced!)
```

(To find the dependence, I have searched the libs for "cl.exe" and noted the compile option or used dumpbin.)

Now, to add to my uncertainty, Visual Studio debugger "Module" window only shows one MSVCRT.dll. Perhaps this is why it appears stable (?) - but I expected the dependencies shown above to come into play – and not such old MSVCRT references (Ps. I have exercised those libs/dlls to access their functionality at run-time & see no change to modules loaded).

So, my questions:

1. Obvious, but: do others share my concern about the apparent mix of C runtimes in this application?
2. To my knowledge**, data types transferred across the dll boundary are only primitives & arrays of primitives. No memory creation/freeing in different CRTs, no file pointers passed, no environment variables requested etc, AFAIK. Also, no structures instanced from a shared header. If I am absolutely correct in this, could this be a reason why mixed CRTs may be working together with my application ok?

** I do need to go through this thoroughly and check this is true.

3. In moving to VS2013 toolchain (compiler/linker), I have in mind to change our exe & libs to use dynamic CRT. My concept is to minimise any possible mix of CRT, so I think the best plan is to make as many libraries as I can control use a single dynamic CRT (MSVCR120.dll?) - as I read somewhere that where multiple dynamic CRTs are to be loaded, a single will actually be used. Can someone confirm this is the case? Is this a reasonable strategy to follow, or, with such a legacy of libraries, is there a better approach?
4. Where a single MSVCRxxx version is to be loaded by multiple dlls/libs, can we say which it will/should be on any particular Windows 7/8/10 pc? (eg, oldest version, newest version, first requirement loaded?)

I may be over-thinking this, but the various warnings online and my seemingly mixed CRT application have me concerned.

I think that covers it. Any input is very much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Edit 20th July 2016:
I just came across this article, which I thought was relevant to anyone considering the same questions: http://www.davidlenihan.com/2008/01/choosing_the_correct_cc_runtim.html

Thanks!

Comment: If your code base compiles, runs, and passes your massive suite of regression tests with the newer compiler, then what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks Brain for the comment, and yes, it's a good point, but the concern I express is that run-time issues are not necessarily going to be picked up by testing. It's the Rumsfeld "known unknowns" in that - to my eye, it looks bad and (I think) should cause issues - it doesn't right now but is something I feel I need to both understand and make a strategy for. I'm hoping that folks out there may be able to say, "yes, it's bad. Sort it out...<here's how I would do that>", or "not actually an issue because..."

Comment: The issues in the link you provided are valid.  The only one I have personally encountered is with memory allocation.  Each CRT (and even the same CRT when statically linked into multiple DLL) have their own memory allocation heap so having one DLL allocate memory and a different DLL free memory can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your #3 strategy to be the best approach. lib C in your example case may be a problem.
The Exact DLL loaded is specified by the %PATH% environment variable if not found in "."[microsoft DLL search order link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)
  You can use Dependancy walker [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com)from Microsoft to see what DLLs are going to be used by an application.

This should resolve all but your LibC case.

Comment: Hi Ross, just a quick thanks for your answer. 
Best regards, D